# Find three numbers in a BST summing to a number

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Each node stores an integer and a target sum given a binary search tree. Find the indices of three nodes in the tree that sum up to the target (Any triplet will do). 
The index of a node is the index in the inorder traversal of the binary search tree starting from 0.
**My thoughts :** 
One way is to make an inorder traversal of the tree and push the elements in a list.

 Now fix a number, and then we have to find two numbers in the list that sum up to a particular sum.
This will require O(n) space. So I wondered if there could be a way to do it in O(1) space.

**Trying to solve it on O(1) space** :
  I tried to solve a simpler problem given a BST and a target sum to find two numbers in BST that sum to target. The function should return the indices of the nodes. And we cannot choose the same node again. 
Now I can do an inorder traversal like :

```
visit(Node node) : 
   if node == null:
        return;
   else:
         visit(node.left)
         node.value
/* Now suppose x + y = sum and x = node.value so I have to 
 search sum-y in the BST But how do I ensure that I don't end up choosing the same node as the one with value x (Althought different nodes with same values are fine*/
         visit(node.right)
```

I just resorted to a simpler problem for easy discussion. The problem comes when I have to make sure that I don't choose the same node and also I have to return the indices of the two nodes which sum to target (any two nodes will do)

Comment: Well with this algorithm you don't need a separte list. A tree also might be traversed in O(N).

Comment: Once you have two numbers, you obtain the third by difference and look it up in time O(log(n)). I don't think that you can avoid trying all pairs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But how do I choose the two numbers without storing them in the list?

Comment: They are already in the tree, no need to copy.

Comment: @YvesDaoust probably I do not understand your argument. I am adding my thoughts to the original question. Let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Find out how to *enumerate* the nodes of a binary tree.